# Creating functions using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I created a function which takes 2 parameters (Name of the array, Size of the array) and what I did was take the max element of the array minus the minimum.
But what i want to do now is create the same function using pointers, but i always get a result which is 0 for some reason.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const void pntArray(int arrName[], unsigned sizeOfArray);//The first function which takes the size of the array and the array name and prints the sub of the max-min
void pntTheArray(int *(arrName), unsigned sizeOfArray);//Version of the first function, using pointers

int main()
{
    int someArr[3]={7,2,6};
    int pointerArray[5]={7,6,5,4,10};
    pntArray(someArr, 3);//Example of the function without the pointers
    pntTheArray(someArr, 3);//Example of the function with the pointers
}


 void pntTheArray(int *arrName, unsigned sizeOfArray){
int max = 0;
int min = 999999;
for (int x = 0;x<sizeOfArray;x++){
    if (*arrName+x>max){
        max  = *arrName;
    }
    if(*arrName+x<min){
        min = *arrName;
    }
}
cout<<"The maximum element minus the the minimum element is: "<<(unsigned)(max-min)<<endl;
}

const void pntArray(int arrName[], unsigned sizeOfArray){
    int max=0;
    int min = 999999;
    for (int x = 0;x<sizeOfArray;x++){
        if(arrName[x]>max){
            max = arrName[x];
        }
        if (arrName[x]<min){
            min = arrName[x];
        }
    }cout<<"The maximum element minus the the minimum element is: "<<(unsigned)(max-min)<<endl;}
```

I want to make a version of the first array, basically.
So where's the mistake that i'm making in order to get only 0 as a result for the second function?

Comment: BTW `int arrName[]` means exactly the same as `int *arrName` when it appears as a function's parameter, so you have absolutely no reason to "change" your code from "array" to "pointer" - both versions work with pointers. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/509868) for details.

Comment: I know that it works, but I have to make 2 versions of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you are using in the `if` statement:

```
*arrName+x>max
```

is equivalent to:

```
 arrName[0]+x > max
```

That's not what you need. You need to use:

```
 *(arrName+x) > max
```

or

```
 arrName[x] > max
```

You'll need to change a few more lines that suffer from the same error.

Change:

```
if (*arrName+x>max){
    max  = *arrName;
}
if(*arrName+x<min){
    min = *arrName;
}
```

to

```
if (*(arrName+x) > max){
    max  = *(arrName+x);
}
if(*(arrName+x) < min){
    min = *(arrName+x);
}
```

Comment: I still get 0 as a result :/

Comment: I added it both in the max and in the min expression under it. Thanks for the help! ^^

Answer (score 2):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
 if (*arrName+x>max) {
```

The `*` (deereference operation) has a higher precedence than the `+` operation. [See operator precedence.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) So what you are really doing is this:

```
 if ( (*arrName) + x > max) {
```

You should be using:

```
if (*(arrName + x) > max) {
```

or

```
if (arrName[x] > max) {
```

The reason you get zero is because you do it in several places. Try this:

```
void pntTheArray(int *arrName, unsigned sizeOfArray){
    int max = 0, min = 999999;
    for (int x = 0;x<sizeOfArray;x++){
        cout << "i: " << x << " val: " << *(arrName+x) << "\n";
        if (*(arrName+x)>max){
            max  = *(arrName+x); // Note you weren't setting this correctly either!!!
        }
        if(*(arrName+x)<min){
            min = *(arrName+x); // Note you weren't setting this correctly either!!!
        }
    }
    cout<<"The maximum element minus the the minimum element is: "<<(unsigned)(max-min)<<endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/RrlQVr)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses when dereferencing `arrName`

Instead of

```
*arrName + x>max
```

You should

```
*(arrName + x)>max
```